# Make a web listener class publicly available

Tags: rest-api, post

I am implementing a web listener class and want to listen to POST requests.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MyListener/*')
global with sharing class ListnerClassTest {
    @HttpPost
    global static String makeAction (String ID, String Value) {
        return 'Got it!';
    }
}
```

When I make POST requests to this class, I am getting **`401 unauthorized error`**. Can someone help me how to expose my class for apps to make post request without oauth or authentication.
Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: You could use a public force.com site and a VF page to take post parameters then return the results to the page as XML or JSON

Comment: @Eric I contemplated on that idea. But is it possible to include an oauth token in the request and get it authorized instead of creating a new force.com site?

Comment: @krish - You said you did not want to use oauth. If you want to use oauth then continue with the REST resource

Comment: hey Krish.. had you created a public site to access this web service ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to authenticate your requests (Force.com hints you on that with a 401 response).

Since you are using postman, follow this guide how to authenticate it using oAuth2: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/helpers

You need to create a connected application in your org before that, though. Follow this guide: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com (see "Configuring OAuth 2.0 Access for your Application").

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using invalid session id.

The best way to check if your server is working fine is to use workbench.

https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Here are steps how to check your new Rest API.
1) Login to workbench
2) go to utilities -> rest explore
3) Enter your api url for ex.  services/apexrest/MyListener
4) select post method
5) Enter JSON and hit execute

JSON EX:

```
{
"ID":"12345",
"Value": "abcd"
}
```

if you see proper response then there is noting work in your api and you need to check your client side code.

I suspect that there is issue with your client side code and you are not passing the session id or access token properly.